# Importing text file to 2d list in python adds single quotes

Tags: python, file, multidimensional-array, import

I have a database that contains records of all the budgies in my aviary. It also includes breeding information. I recently made a script in python that prints out the family tree of any specific bird. However, I did this by creating a 2D list in the script file. This means that any changes I make to the database are not reflected in the program. To improve this, I have exported the data to a txt file, with the hope of importing that file into my script as a 2D list.

The text file represents the data delimited by commas, where the first column is the bird's name, the second column is its mother, the third column is its father. For example:

```
"Myriad","Ruby","Indiana"
"Vanadium","Peeper","Jeckyll"
"Kevin","Vanadium","Manganese"
```

I've read lots of explanations of how to do this and am currently using the code:

```
with open("BudgieStock.txt") as textFile:
    birdList = [line.split() for line in textFile]
```

However, if I then print the array it adds an extra single quote around each list:

```
[[' "Myriad","Ruby","Indiana" '], [' "Vanadium","Peeper","Jeckyll" '], [' "Kevin","Vanadium","Manganese" ']]
```

This stops my program from working. I've looked everywhere but can't find any explanation of why this is happening or how to stop it.

What I want is simply:

```
[["Myriad","Ruby","Indiana"], ["Vanadium","Peeper","Jeckyll"], ["Kevin","Vanadium","Manganese"]]
```

The program worked well when I hardcoded the list into the script file. I tried removing the single quotes using:

```
[t.replace("'", "") for t in birdList]
```

But was given the error, "'List' object has no attribute 'replace'".

If anyone can explain why this is happening and how to fix it, I would greatly appreciate it. This is my first time importing files using python (C++ background).

Answer (score 1):

`line.split()` splits by whitespace. You want to split by commas.

```
with open("BudgieStock.txt") as textFile:
    birdList = [line.split(',') for line in textFile]
```

Also, you need to get rid of the extraneous quotes as well. I'd recommend just leaving them out of your file entirely, but

```
with open("BudgieStock.txt") as textFile:
    birdList = [[i.strip("\"") for i in line.split(',')] for line in textFile]
```

would get rid of them too.

Comment: Thanks, that's a definite improvement! However, each list now ends in a newline character, eg:
    ['Myriad', 'Ruby', 'Indiana\n']

I also pulled the quotes out of my text file.

Comment: Oh, right, python does that. Uh, so far, my solution that has been to call `.strip("\n")`. Something like `[line.strip("\n").split(',') for line in textFile]`